# JS: Change google maps style from hybrid to map and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a div id="map" as required and trying to modify the type of the map from satellite to roadmap and vice-versa, but it is not working.
Let´s see some code

```
function sat() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
map.google.maps.setMapTypeId('hybrid');
}
```

When I click on a button, it calls the sat() function but got the error:

```
mapFunctions.js:1970 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does `map.**google.maps.**setMapTypeId('hybrid')` come from? Looks like a typo to me.  If that doesn't help, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Well, I am trying to place some GoogleMaps SDK code and that´s what is in the documentation

Comment: Should be `map.setMapTypeId('hybrid');`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found another way to get the map and it is working now.